# Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references

Tags: android, xml, themes

I am getting this message in my xml

**"Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references."**
So can you please tell me that what is combo theme and how to implement this in my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close your layout files in the editor and restart your Eclipse.

If you are using Android 3.0 and above on your Graphical Layout. Try changing it to Android 2.2 or 2.3.

Comment: my friend it is not the solution it is just a way to run from our problem. I want to know why this occured and want to know how to overcome of it by proper solution.** by restarting it will again occur after sometime**

Comment: I have the project, in manifest.xml file the android:minSdkVersion="7" means Android 2.1, in Graphical Layout of abc.xml file it display the same message "Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references."   then i changed the API from the Editor area, then it will hide the message..... means its a issue of different API....

Answer (score 0):

update your Android studio to latest version and after that update your gradle

Comment: This should be a comment.